# Change in RetailLoyaltyCollection Class methods

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to customize the way AX is calculating loyalty customers points and updating process. I beleive they are using class RetailLoyaltyCollection's methods updateLoyaltyUsedPoints and updateLoyaltyIssuedPoints to updated points in database.

But it seems that the code I wrote in these methods has no effect.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in this regard or any other way to hit some code when a customer gets points, basically we are trying to send SMS when customer gets loyalty points, SMS functionality is working fine, all we need is to call it when customer gets point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your code is not run? Maybe you forgot the [incremental CIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg839855.aspx) update?

Maybe you need some reverse engineering, say understand and use the [Cross reference tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa626961.aspx)?
Sometimes simple questions do have simple answers and that tool is full of them.